# Flutter DateTime formate in Time ago in ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I have PageView.builder Widget, which is fetching data from my server.

```
PageView.builder(
    itemCount: _newsList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            if(_newsList.isNotEmpty){
            return Text(_newsList[index].posted!);
       } else Container("Empty");
}
)
```

I have imported https://pub.dev/packages/timeago
but can not use it in `PageView.builder()`.

Please help me to sort it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use, import timeago as:

```
import 'package:timeago/timeago.dart' as timeago;
```

To use timeago in widget:

```
Text(timeago.format(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(dateTimeMillis))); //or other DateTime object
```

Comment: I am getting Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int?'

Comment: What is the data type of your posted variable? And what data it contains?

Comment: Done! Sir, previously it was DateTime but now I changed it to  String Type. Now working sir.

Comment: Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 String timeAgo(DateTime fatchedDate) {
        DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();
    
        var different = currentDate.difference(fatchedDate);
    
        if (different.inDays > 365)
          return "${(different.inDays / 365).floor()} ${(different.inDays / 365).floor() == 1 ? "year" : "years"} ago";
        if (different.inDays > 30)
          return "${(different.inDays / 30).floor()} ${(different.inDays / 30).floor() == 1 ? "month" : "months"} ago";
        if (different.inDays > 7)
          return "${(different.inDays / 7).floor()} ${(different.inDays / 7).floor() == 1 ? "week" : "weeks"} ago";
        if (different.inDays > 0)
          return "${different.inDays} ${different.inDays == 1 ? "day" : "days"} ago";
        if (different.inHours > 0)
          return "${different.inHours} ${different.inHours == 1 ? "hour" : "hours"} ago";
        if (different.inMinutes > 0)
          return "${different.inMinutes} ${different.inMinutes == 1 ? "minute" : "minutes"} ago";
        if (different.inMinutes == 0) return 'Just Now';
    
        return fatchedDate.toString();
      }
```

Comment: I am getting Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime?'